# _id : replace ObjectId to hexa value or string and indexing it

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection with hexa address like this :

```
address: "dbaf14e1c476e76ea05a8b71921a46d6b06f0a950f17c5f9f1a03b8fae467f10"
```

They are all unique, so I thought I could store them in the _id field.

But I'm asking myself 2 question :

First, is there a better way to store such hexa value ? Or a String is the best option ?

And, if I set my _id field as a String, how is the indexing going to happen ? I know we can't change the index type of an _id field but is the default index type (exemple: `db.collection.createIndex({address: 1})` ) working on string ?

I used to do

```
db.collection.createIndex({address: "text"})
```

Comment: See this documentation on the [_id field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/index.html#the-id-field).

Comment: Yes I already did but it's not clear about the indexing, and the same about the indexes type, which one is the best for strings and is the default one is good for them ?

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation it will be a [unique](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/index.html) index (always) on the `_id` field.